# My js code is not detecting an empty object

Tags: javascript, debugging, lodash

I'm not a complete beginner but that one is blocking me and my colleagues.

I have an application that is making calls with an empty body to my CRM which in turns responds with a 400 `bad request` exception.

I'm logging calls on datadog and I can see that the body is indeed empty despite my attempts to avoid making the call when that is the case.

Can you help? Do you have any ideas?

My code before calling the CRM repository method:

```js
if (!isEmpty(personDto)) {
  response = {
    status: response.status.concat(`Person has been updated : ${JSON.stringify(personDto)}`),
    personDto: personDto,
  };
  await this.pipedriveRepository.updatePerson(body.current.id, personDto);
} else {
  response = {
    status: response.status.concat(`Person has not changed and no update were made`),
    personDto: personDto,
  };
}

return response;
```

I'm using lodash isEmpty.
However, the method updatePerson is beeing called even when an object is empty, but only in production, not locally when I artificially pass an empty object.

```js
async updatePerson(id: number, person: IPipedrivePersonDto): Promise < PipedrivePerson > {
  const personApi = new this.pipeDriveClient.PersonsApi();

  if (isEmpty(person) || Object.keys(person).length === 0) {
    throw new Error(`Can't update a person with no body: ` + JSON.stringify(person));
  }

  try {
    const {
      data
    } = (await personApi.updatePerson(id, person)) as PersonResponse;
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    if ((e as PipedriveResponseException).context.status === 400) {
      return person as PipedrivePerson;
    }
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Here I make the verification again and no error is thrown. However a calls to my CRM pipedrive is made and an empty body is logged on datadog.
opts and person are empty

```js
{
  "id": "AQAAAYOxHSvXy25ofAAAAA4SFM3WkFBQldILXNoZVMxU2R3QUI",
  "content": {
    "timestamp": "2022-10-07T06:23:42.551Z",
    "tags": [
      "service:growth",
      "filename:app.log",
      "sourcecategory:sourcecode",
      "source:nodejs",
      "buildpackversion:dev",
      "dyno:web.1",
      "dynotype:web",
      "env:prod",
      "version:1.0.0"
    ],
    "host": "24f45b35-3ea7-487f-9c25-2372d17ceb",
    "service": "growth",
    "message": "POST /hooks/pipedrive/persons/updated",
    "attributes": {
      "timestamp": "2022-10-07 06:23:42",
      "dd": {
        "service": "growth"
      },
      "time": "2022-10-07T06:23:42.551Z",
      "response": {
        "body": "Person data has been cleant\r\nNo new email to validate\r\nPerson already has a valid email address\r\nPerson has been updated : {}",
        "status": 201
      },
      "level": "info"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's not a subtle thing about javascript I am not understanding there.
Since I'm double checking with Object.keys, it should not be a lodash issue.

What can I do now? I'm running out of ideas, already tried all basic stuff.

Comment: Not really enough info here to diagnose the problem, what you need to do is break this down to a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error locally, it only happens in production, and if I repeat the body logged on datadog, I don't have the error. Which alternative to console log can I use to get a better idea of the object content?

Comment: @Sébastien if you can't `console.log` , use `util.inspect` https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-showhidden-depth-colors since it returns a string

Answer (score 0):

The object is probably not empty. There are countless possible causes for a prop not being included after calling `JSON.stringify`.
Check for private properties on your dto class. Or a custom toJSON function.
Try logging not only the stringified object, but the object itself with a `console.log`.

```js
class Person {
    #privateProp = 1;
}
console.log(new Person()); // => { #privateProp: 1 }
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Person())); // => {}
```